# Finding the general formula for the sequence defined by $u_1 = 1$ and $u_{n+1} = u_n + 1 + \sqrt{u_n+3}$

Tags: difference-equations

Let be given sequence $(u_n)$ satisfying:
$$u_1 = 1, \quad u_{n+1} = u_n + 1 + \sqrt{u_n+3}, \forall n \geq 1.$$
I tried

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
RSolve[{a[x, n + 1] == a[x, n]  + 1 +  Sqrt[ a[x, n] + 3], 
  a[x, 1] == 1}, a[x, n], n]
```

> {{a[x, n] -> 6 - 6 n + n^2}, {a[x, n] -> -2 + 2 n + n^2}}

With the answer `a[x, n] -> -2 + 2 n + n^2}`. I tried

```
Table[-2 + 2 n + n^2, {n, 10}]
```

> {1, 6, 13, 22, 33, 46, 61, 78, 97, 118}

By hand, I get $u_2 = 1 + 1 + \sqrt{4} = 4. $

I also tried

```
RSolve[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + 1 + Sqrt[a[n] + 3], a[1] == 1}, a[n], n]
```

and get the same answer.

Where is wrong in my code to find $u_n$?

Comment: Your recursion relation can be transformed into the difference equation, which can be written as an ordinary differential equation, which has an analytic solution. This allows to obtain an accurate asymptotic. Maybe it hints that your recursion can be solved as well.

Comment: It seems have a bug with `RSolve`. Another question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/293296/how-can-i-find-some-first-terms-of-a-sequence

Answer (score 3):

It could be that there is a closed form solution. Following considerations demonstrate that it cannot be simple. Important message is that $u_n$, besides quadratic grows demonstrated in the other answer, has sub-leading logarithmic terms.

Let us first reformulate the recurrence using the $t_n^2=u_n+3$ substitution. We get
$$
t_{n+1}^2=t_n^2+t_n+1,\\
t_1=2.
$$
MA cannot solve this recursion.

However, it can be reformulated introducing a difference $y_n=t_{n+1}-t_n$. We get
$$
y_n(y_n+2t_n)=t_n+1.
$$

This can approximately be written as an ordinary differential equation (ODE)
$$
x'(t)\big(x'(t)+t\big)=t+1,\\
x(1)=2.
$$

This can be solved analytically with MA

```
DSolve[{y'[x] (y'[x] + 2 y[x]) == y[x] + 1, y[1] == 2}, y[x], x]
```

we select the growing solution and define

```
f[x_] := 
 InverseFunction[-2 Log[-#1 + Sqrt[1 + #1 + #1^2]] + 
     3/2 Log[-1 - 2 #1 + 2 Sqrt[1 + #1 + #1^2]] + #1 + Sqrt[
     1 + #1 + #1^2] &][x + 1/2 (2 + 2 Sqrt[7] - 4 Log[-2 + Sqrt[7]] + 
      3 Log[-5 + 2 Sqrt[7]])]
```

Let us verify the accuracy.

i. Generate log-mesh for plotting purposes. Represent only 20 points in the range $[1, 10000]$

```
kmx = 20;
nmx = 100000;
p = Exp[Log[nmx]/kmx] // N
ni = Table[t = Round[p^(i - 1)]; t, {i, 1, kmx}] // DeleteDuplicates
```

ii. Generate the solution of the 2nd recursion.

```
a = {2};
Do[AppendTo[a, x = Last[a]; N[Sqrt[x^2 + x + 1]]], {n, nmx}]
an = Table[{i, a[[i]]}, {i, ni}]
```

iii.  Generate the solution of the 1st recursion.

```
u = {1};
Do[AppendTo[u, x = Last[u]; N[x + 1 + Sqrt[x + 3]]], {n, nmx}]
un = Table[{i, u[[i]]}, {i, ni}]
```

iv.  Plot 2nd recursion vs analytic solution

```
g1 = LogLogPlot[f[n], {n, 1, nmx}];
g2 = ListLogLogPlot[an, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Orange]];
Show[{g1, g2}]
```

[image]

And here is the same graph with the polynomial asymptotic.
[image]

v. Plot 1st recursion vs analytic solution

```
g3 = LogLogPlot[f[n]^2 - 3, {n, 1, nmx},PlotTheme -> "NeonColor"];
g4 = ListLogLogPlot[un, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Blue]];
Show[{g3, g4}]
```

[image]

And here is the same graph with the polynomial asymptotic.
[image]

Finally, in the case someone needs a practical formula working in the whole range. One can transform the original recursion into a differential equation with the solution

```
v[n_] := -2 + 2 ProductLog[-1, -3 E^(-(5/2) - n/2)] + 
  ProductLog[-1, -3 E^(-(5/2) - n/2)]^2
```

Using properties of the Lambert W function one can with high accuracy write

```
g[n_] := Log[3 E^(-(5/2) - n/2)] - Log[5/2 + n/2 - Log[3]] + 
  Log[5/2 + n/2 - Log[3]]/Log[3 E^(-(5/2) - n/2)] + (Log[5/2 + n/2 - Log[3]]*(Log[5/2 + n/2 - Log[3]] - 2))/(2* Log[3 E^(-(5/2) - n/2)]^2)

w[n_] := -2 + 2*g[n] + g[n]^2
```

This function has the following asymptotic form

```
wa[n_]:=1/4 (-3 + n (6 + n)) - (3 + n) Log[3] + Log[3]^2
```

Comment: First, you obtain an approximate solution according to your "This can approximately be written as an ordinary differential equation (ODE)". Second, `InverseFunction[-2 Log[-#1 + Sqrt[1 + #1 + #1^2]] + 
     3/2 Log[-1 - 2 #1 + 2 Sqrt[1 + #1 + #1^2]] + #1 + Sqrt[
     1 + #1 + #1^2] &][x + 1/2 (2 + 2 Sqrt[7] - 4 Log[-2 + Sqrt[7]] + 
      3 Log[-5 + 2 Sqrt[7]])]` is neither a closed-form expression nor an analytic expression (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Closed-form+expression&title=Special:Search&ns0=1) for the definitions).

Comment: Third, can you kindly compare your  result with `u[n_]:=1/4*n^2-3` obtained by me? TIA.

Comment: `Table[{Log[f[n]^2 - 3], Log[1/4*n^2 - 3]}, {n, 10, 10010, 500}] // N` results in `{{3.89177, 3.09104}, {11.1196, 11.0825}, {12.4699, 12.4491}, {13.2682,
   13.2534}, {13.837, 13.8255}, {14.2793, 14.2698}, {14.6412, 
  14.6331}, {14.9475, 14.9404}, {15.2131, 15.2068}, {15.4475, 
  15.4418}, {15.6573, 15.6521}, {15.8471, 15.8423}, {16.0205, 
  16.0161}, {16.18, 16.1759}, {16.3277, 16.3239}, {16.4653, 
  16.4617}, {16.594, 16.5906}, {16.7149, 16.7117}, {16.829, 
  16.8259}, {16.9368, 16.9339}, {17.0392, 17.0364}}`. The difference  decreases as `n` increases.

Comment: Also `g3 = LogLogPlot[f[n]^2 - 3, {n, 1, nmx}, PlotTheme -> "NeonColor"];
g4 = ListLogLogPlot[un, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Blue]]; g5 = 
 LogLogPlot[1/4*n^2 - 3, {n, 1, nmx}, PlotTheme -> "BoldColor"];
Show[{g3, g4, g5}]` shows the same lines. Compare `InverseFunction[-2 Log[-#1 + Sqrt[1 + #1 + #1^2]] + 
     3/2 Log[-1 - 2 #1 + 2 Sqrt[1 + #1 + #1^2]] + #1 + Sqrt[
     1 + #1 + #1^2] &][x + 1/2 (2 + 2 Sqrt[7] - 4 Log[-2 + Sqrt[7]] + 
      3 Log[-5 + 2 Sqrt[7]])]` witn `1/4x^2-3`. Hope you feel the difference.

Comment: Your termin "lowest order order asymptotic" is not exact. I find "polynomial asymptotic"  more exact.  I think the complicated approach used by you is a road to nowhere: nothing better than `1/4 n^2-3`.

Comment: One more approach: consider ODE `DSolve[{u'[n] == Sqrt[u[n] + 3], u[1] == 1}, u[n], n]`, where  the term `1` is omitted, instead of RE under consideration. Then `{{u[n] -> 1/4 (-3 + 6 n + n^2)}}`.

Comment: Can you elaborate your claim "One can transform the original recursion into a differential equation with the solution", giving us details? I obtain by `sol = DSolve[{u'[n] == 1 + Sqrt[u[n] + 3], u[1] == 1}, u[n], n] // 
  FullSimplify`  the following result `{{u[n] -> -2 + 
    ProductLog[E^((3 - n)/2)] (2 + ProductLog[E^((3 - n)/2)])}}` and a warning "Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information." Plot `Plot[u[n] /. sol, {n, 1, 14}]` clearly shows that `sol` is not correct.

Comment: @user64494 I haven't put the solution because I obtained it partially by hand. I sketch the idea here. One starts with ODE that you wrote. It is convenient to reformulate it for the inverse function. Next, solve it (+ initial conditions) with MA. Finally, invert the solution paying attention to the branch of `ProductLog`. In fact, there is only one branch (-1) that yields a real solution. MA does not know the asymptotic expansion of the `ProductLog` for this branch. Therefore, one needs to do it by hand following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions.

Comment: I don't find your reply satisfactory. In particular, it's unclear to me why " It is convenient to reformulate it for the inverse function".

Comment: @user64494 So that it can be integrated by the separation of variables. This is the standard method for the solution of first-order autonomous ordinary differential equations. You can ask an independent question, as why MA cannot properly solve it, and what are the workarounds.

Comment: Thank you, this is a serious argument. Can you present the ODE you work with? TIA.  BTW, Maple correctly solves `{u'[n] == 1 + Sqrt[u[n] + 3], u[1] == 1}`.

Comment: Finally, since we don't know error when turning from  RE to ODE, all that has not much sense. At best, our approaches  (with and without ODEs) are  heuristic.  Also it's unclear how to compare the results.

Answer (score 0):

We can find an asymptotic solution by

```
AsymptoticRSolveValue[{u[n + 1] == u[n] + 1 + Sqrt[u[n] + 3],   u[1] == 1}, u[n], {n ,Infinity,3}]
```

> `6 - 6 n + n^2`

Addition. The result of

```
nl = NestList[# + 1 + Sqrt[3 + #] &, 1.000000000000,  10^5];
 fL = #^2 - 6 # + 5 & /@ (Range@Length@nl); ListPlot[{fL/nl}]
```

[image]

suggests that the result of `AsymptoticRSolve` has the correct order of the growth up to the multiplier `1/4`.

Let us find an asymptotic solution of `{u[n + 1] == u[n] + 1 + Sqrt[u[n] + 3],   u[1] == 1}` in the form `u[n_] := a*n^2 + b*n + c`.

We substitute it in the recurrence equation and find the asmptotic at infinity by

```
Series[u[n + 1] - u[n] - 1 - Sqrt[u[n] + 3], {n, Infinity, 3}, 
Assumptions -> {a, b, c} \[Element] Reals && n > 1] // Normal
```

> `-1 + a + b - b/( 2 Sqrt[a]) + ((12 a - 5 b^2 + 4 a c) (12 a - b^2 + 4 a c))/( 128 a^(7/2) n^3) + (b (12 a - b^2 + 4 a c))/( 16 a^(5/2) n^2) + (-12 a + b^2 - 4 a c)/( 8 a^(3/2) n) + (-Sqrt[a] + 2 a) n`

We want to cancel as many as possible terms in the above.

```
Solve[-Sqrt[a] + 2 a == 0, a, Reals]
```

gives `a -> 1/4`, The term `-1 + a + b - b/( 2 Sqrt[a])==-3/4` cannot be cancelled. Now

```
Solve[{0 == -12 a + b^2 - 4 a c, 12 a - 5 b^2 + 4 a c == 0} /. 
a -> 1/4, {b, c}, Reals]
```

> `{{b -> 0, c -> -3}}`

Hence, we  draw the conclusion that `u[n_]:=1/4*n^2-3` can be taken as an asymptotic solution.

Comment: But $n^2-6 n+6$ does not satisfy  $u_{n+1} = u_n + 1 + \sqrt{u_n+3}$

$$ $$
`func[n_] = 6 - 6 n + n^2;`
`func[2] == func[1] + 1 + Sqrt[func[1] + 3]`
`(*False*)`

Comment: @ydd: Yes, of course, "$6 - 6 n + n^2$ does not satisfy $u_{n+1} = u_n + 1 + \sqrt{u_n+3}$". This is an asymptotic formula for $u_n$ as $n$ tends to infinity. Look in the documentation tp `AsymptoticRSolveValue`

Comment: I don't think it's asymptotically correct either:
$$ $$
`nl = NestList[# + 1 + Sqrt[3 + #] &, 1., 10000];`
`fL = #^2 & /@ (Range@Length@nl);`
`ListPlot[{nl, fL}, PlotLegends -> {"true values", "asymp. values"}]`
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g9D4.png)
$$ $$
I am also confused why `AsymptoticRSolveValue` can't solve the seemingly simpler `AsymptoticRSolveValue[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + Sqrt[a[n]], a[1] == 1}, 
 a[n], n -> Infinity]`

Comment: Hope that `Series[(6 - 6 (1 + n) + (1 + n)^2)/(6 - 6 n + n^2 + 1 + 
    Sqrt[6 - 6 n + n^2 + 3]), {n, Infinity, 2}]` which results in`1+1/n+2/n^2+O[1/n]^3` is  convincing. The difference in `ListPlot[{nl, fL}]` is caused by big round-of errors. "can't solve the seemingly simpler" is not any argument at all.

Comment: Okay I am convinced. (Maybe even stronger: `Limit[func[n + 1]/(func[n] + 1 + Sqrt[func[n] + 3]), n -> Infinity]` `(*1*)`

But it is still unclear why this is also given as the exact answer by `RSolve` as well.  , because it only satisfies the recurrence relation at infinity

Comment: I don't know how to explain the results of `RSolve[{a[x, n + 1] == a[x, n]  + 1 +  Sqrt[ a[x, n] + 3], 
  a[x, 1] == 1}, a[x, n], n]`.

Comment: The result of `nl = NestList[# + 1 + Sqrt[3 + #] &, 1.000000000000, 
  10^5]; fL = #^2 - 6 # + 5 & /@ (Range@Length@nl); ListPlot[{fL/nl}`
suggests that the multiplier 1/4 could be omitted in `AsymptoticRSolveValue[{u[n + 1] == u[n] + 1 + Sqrt[u[n] + 3],   u[1] == 1}, u[n], {n ,Infinity,3}]`.

Comment: Indeed, `Series[-1/4*(6 - 6*(n + 1) + (n + 1)^2) + 1/4*(6 - 6 n + n^2) + 1 + 
  Sqrt[1/4*(6 - 6 n + n^2) + 3], {n, Infinity, 3}]` performs `3/4+9/(4 n)+27/(4 n^2)+243/(16 n^3)+O[1/n]^4`

Comment: CASE:5093486 has been submitted by me.