# How can I find some first terms of a sequence?

Tags: sequence

I have a sequence knowing that $a_1=15$, $a_{n+1} = a_n + \sqrt{2a_{n+1}-a_n}$. I want to find some the first terms. I tried by my hand

```
k := 15;
Solve[x == k + Sqrt[2 x - k], x]
```

> {{x -> 20}}

```
k := 20;
    Solve[x == k + Sqrt[2 x - k], x]
```

> {{x -> 21 + Sqrt[21]}}

I am trying to find a general formulas. I tried

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
RSolve[{a[x, n + 1] == a[x, n]  + Sqrt[ 2 a[x, n + 1] - a[x, n] ], 
   a[x, 1] == 15}, a[x, n], n] // FullSimplify
```

> {{a[x, n] -> (-6 + n) (-4 + n)}, {a[x, n] -> (2 + n) (4 + n)}}

The out put, e.g $(2 + n) (4 + n)$ is incorrect, I think that.

How to find  some first terms of the sequence $a_1=15$, $a_{n+1} = a_n + \sqrt{2a_{n+1}-a_n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to give you some of the first terms.

```
sol=15;
Table[sol=b/.ToRules[FullSimplify[Reduce[{a==sol,b==a+Sqrt[2b-a]},b]]],{4}]
```

which returns

```
{20,
 21+Sqrt[21],
 22+Sqrt[21]+Sqrt[22+Sqrt[21]], 
 23+Sqrt[21]+Sqrt[22+Sqrt[21]]+Sqrt[23+Sqrt[21]+Sqrt[22+Sqrt[21]]]
}
```

If you want a decimal approximation of that then follow it with

```
N[%]
```

and get

```
{20.,25.5826,31.7384,38.4602}
```

Test that brutally.  Is it exactly correct?

That does not give you a closed form algebraic solution but it does give you "some first terms of your sequence." Remove the `FullSimplify` to make it somewhat faster, but then you won't see the structure of the solutions.